# Controller bindings for nested controllers with {{render}} helper in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm having troubles detecting property changes in nested controllers.

Here's my simplified code:

**ActionCardController**

```
ActionCardController = Ember.ObjectController.extend ActivatableHandles,

  needs: ['actionCards', 'handle-connector']
```

**HandleConnectorController**

```
HandleConnectorController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
  content: {}

  testProperty: (->
    @get('somePropertyThatChanges')
  ).property('someOtherProperty')
```

**ActionCard template**

```
<div ...
  ...
  ...
  ...
  {{render 'handle-connector' this}}
  ...
  {{controllers.handle-connector.testProperty}}
</div>
```

As shown, I have a nested "handle-connector" controller (with multiple properties) with its own view and template which needs to be rendered inside of ActionCard template. Everything renders and behaves fine within handle-connector context but I cant't seem to access testProperty in the parent controller (which is a computed property on nested handle-controller). I can only access the initial property value but once it gets changed in the nested controller, it does not refresh in the parent controller (ActionCard).

If I don't specify a model in the render helper, calling just:

```
{{render 'handle-connector'}}
```

...then the property gets refreshed in the parent controller as well and this approach works fine. But when I'm rendering multiple ActionCards, I get the error "*You can only use the {{render}} helper once without a model object as its second argument*". What's the correct way of dealing with this situation?

Answer (score 2):

`needs` accesses a singleton instance of the controller, whereas `render` with a model creates a unique instance of the controller for that particular template being injected.

You can access the parent controller from the rendered controller using `this.parentController` from the child controller, which gives you a means of communication from the child to the parent.

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/buzud/1/edit